# Jquery change function is not working on some server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code works perfect on my localhost but not working on my clients site why ?

JQUERY

```
function someClickEventFunction(){
  $("#checkin").val("2").change();
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="checkin">
    <option value="1">Default</option>
    <option valeu="2">Blah</option>
</select>
```

When this code runs the select options get cleared instead of changing !

Comment: Maybe because of the typo `valeu`.

Comment: did you upload the file to the remote host? also you could try `.trigger('change')` instead

Comment: First I  used this code  . .but did not worked

Comment: You may also tried with .on("change") also.

Comment: You may also use .bind("change") with html element.

Answer (score 0):

Try once

```
 <select id="checkin">
 <option value="1">Default</option>
 <option value="2">Blah</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a typo(**valeu="2"**) in your html. Also, I don't think you need to trigger change() event just to change value.

**Here you go:**

```js
function someClickEventFunction(){
  $("#checkin").val("2");
}

someClickEventFunction()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="checkin">
        <option value="1">Default</option>
        <option value="2">Blah</option>
    </select>
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks,

Ashok